# writing to SD card in android

Tags: android, external, sd-card

```
public void initCache(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
    //Find the dir to save cached images
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"myapp");
    else
        cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
    if(!cacheDir.exists())
        cacheDir.mkdirs();
}
```

I have the right permission in manifest file and also I have th sd card installed. But in spite of this my app is writing to internal storage. I am using Motorola Atrix.

Comment: What is the value of `android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState()`?  that might give you a clue as to what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

> `Environment.getExternalStorageState()` returns path to internal SD mount point like "/mnt/sdcard"

No, `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` refers to whatever the device manufacturer considered to be "external storage". On some devices, this is removable media, like an SD card. On some devices, this is a portion of on-device flash. Here, "external storage" means "the stuff accessible via USB Mass Storage mode when mounted on a host machine", at least for Android 1.x and 2.x.

> But the question is about external SD. How to get a path like "/mnt/sdcard/external_sd" (it may differ from device to device)?

Android has no concept of "external SD", aside from external storage, as described above.

If a device manufacturer has elected to have external storage be on-board flash and also has an SD card, you will need to contact that manufacturer to determine whether or not you can use the SD card (not guaranteed) and what the rules are for using it, such as what path to use for it.